# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 build target

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, xna-4.0

Is it even possible to add the x64 or "Any CPU" in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 for XNA Windows Game 4.0? I've downloaded the redistributables and stuff like that, but they still did not appear when I try to target other platform than x86. Any suggestions? Pics:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What project/solution type are you creating?

Comment: Visual C# - XNA Windows Game 4.0

Comment: Afaik, XNA 4.0 only supports x86 and does not have x64 assemblies, so Visual Studio basically just prevents you from setting a bitness that won't work for the project.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, please answer; Zhafur, please accept.

Answer (score -1):

this is possible , read [MSDN on 64-Bit Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241066.aspx) and [How to: Configure Projects to Target Platforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328.aspx)

Comment: "We're sorry—the topic that you requested is no longer available. Use the search box to find related information." If I try any of the links there.

Comment: "Debugging on a 64-Bit Platform"

Comment: Did you see the pictures? I don't have the options in the dropdown menu. I can't select it.

Comment: "Debugging on a 64-Bit Platform" really doesn't work .... but the rest are working, but if you get tot the debugging part- thats mean that you solve your problem ?

Comment: No, I can't even target the platform, just looking around, your answer doesn't help at all. You don't understand the question.

Comment: I think the second link should help, if not I will delete the answer